# Finding maximum likelihood estimator from pdf $(\theta +1)x^\theta$ for $0<x<2$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

> Given that 
>   $$F(x)= (\theta +1)x^\theta\qquad \text{for} \qquad 0<x<2$$
>   find maximum likelihood estimator.

My progress:

$L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}(\theta +1)(x_i)^\theta$

$L(\theta) = (\theta +1)\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i)^\theta$

edit* i think this step is wrong and i multiply the left part by $n$ but the solution is still strange.

$l(\theta) =  \log( (\theta +1)\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x_i)^\theta)$

$l(\theta) =  \log( (\theta +1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log((x_i)^\theta))$

$=  \log( (\theta +1) + \theta\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log((x_i)))$

$l'(\theta)= \frac{1}{\theta + 1} + \theta $

now if i equate this to 0 and try to solve i get complex roots, i dont know if ive done something wrong or i am meant to continue?

$\theta$ is strictly positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that the proposed function is a probability distribution function? Here, we still need to verify that $\int_{\Bbb R}F(x)\,\text dx =1$, which isn't true. Thus, I'll assume that the function's support is $[0,1]$ (instead of $[0,2]$). Anyway, your computation of the likelihood is incorrect. Indeed,
$$
L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n F(x_i) \\
= (\theta+1)^n\left( \prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^\theta
$$
with $0<x_i<1$ for all $i$.
The log-likelihood
$$
\ell(\theta) = n\log(\theta+1) + \theta\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i
$$
is differentiated as follows
$$
\ell'(\theta) = \frac{n}{\theta+1} + \sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i \, .
$$
This derivative vanishes at
$$
\theta = -1 -n\bigg/\sum_{i=1}^n \log x_i .
$$
If this local extremum corresponds to a maximum of the likelihood, then the previous equation defines the MLE.
To avoid similar mistakes in future, expand the product $\prod_{i=1}^n$ for $n=1,2, \dots$

Comment: yes of course hah thank you